# Where does Mogul Episerver SEO Mangager store it's data

Tags: episerver

A long shot question, I know. I'm in a new job and I've never worked with EpiServer before, let alone Mogul SEO Manager. The export url data feature in the EpiServer dashboard crashes as there's too much data to export, so I'm trying to go to the source but I can't find it.

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious, but have you checked the Episerver database? See if you can find a table giving some hints. It's not unusual for Episerver modules to create a table in the main db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to find the full list of redirects. They are stored in tblBigTable in the episerver db. I used this query to get them:

```
SELECT 
    pkId
    , DateTime01
    , String04          AS RedirectUrl
    , Indexed_String02  AS RequestUrl
FROM [dbo].[tblBigTable]
WHERE StoreName = 'SeoManagerUrlDatas'
    AND String04 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY pkid DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's still storing its data in the **DDS** (Dynamic Data Store).

In other words, it's stored in a *big table* in the database.

[Here is someone with a problem similar to yours](https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/Episerver-Commerce/Thread-Container/2017/3/can-dds-handle-more-than-10000-rows-/)